# Find the probability of opening all the boxes

Tags: probability

Suppose there are $20$ boxes which $1-20$ are printed on each box. There is a key in each box which are also marked with $1-20$. So only the key with the same number with the box can open it. For example, if you open the $no.2$ box, and find a $no.19$ key, you can use that key to open the $no.19$ box

Now two random boxes are open, what is the probability of opening all the remaining boxes.

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but the only way we can lose is if at least one box contains its own key and is not one of the two randomly selected at the start, right?

Comment: No, there can be a loop - box 1 holds key 2, and box 2 holds key 1.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  if you had only one box that started open, you would need to have the permutation of the keys be a single cycle.  With two boxes open, you can afford two cycles, as long as....